# Divergence theorem approach

Tags: calculus

The question is [image]

I am unable to solve this question. I am confused whether to use the left or right side of the divergence theorem and what region is being asked.

Divergence theorem:-

$\iiint _{V}\left(\mathbf {\nabla } \cdot \mathbf {F} \right)\,dV= \iint {\displaystyle \scriptstyle S}  {\displaystyle (\mathbf {F} \cdot \mathbf {n} )\,dS.} $

Comment: You are given RHS. You need to convert the given flux integral to a triple integral.

Comment: Some context would be nice for this one, otherwise it's a bit vague question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Divergence theorem fundamentally states that the divergence is a measure of how much vector field flux is coming out of a point, so we can add all of the divergence within a closed region to get the total flux leaving the boundary of the region:

[image]

The solid region being considered can be described as:
\begin{align*}
R &= \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 0 \leq x \leq 6,\, 0 \leq y \leq 3,\, 0 \leq z \leq 3-\frac{1}{2}x \right\} \\
&= \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 0 \leq x \leq 6-2z,\, 0 \leq y \leq 3,\, 0 \leq z \leq 3 \right\}
\end{align*}
displayed below:

[image]

We are asked to find the flux coming out of $\partial R$, the boundary of $R$, which consists of 5 faces, of the vector field:
$$ \mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = \langle 2xy, yz^2, xz \rangle $$
This is tedious since the boundary consists of 5 faces for which we have to break down the flux surface integral into 5 surface integrals, each with its own parametrization. Hence, we calculate the divergence of the vector field:
\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} 2xy + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} yz^2 + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} xz \\
&= 2y + z^2 + x
\end{align*}
and apply the Divergence Theorem:
\begin{align*}
\iint_{\partial R} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{s} &= \iiint_R (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}) \, dV \\
&= \iiint_R (x + 2y + z^2) \, dV \\
&= \int_0^3 \int_0^3 \int_0^{6-2z} (x + 2y + z^2) \, dx \, dz \, dy \\
&= \int_0^3 \int_0^3 \left[\frac{(6-2z)^2}{2} + (6-2z)(2y + z^2) \right] \, dz \, dy \\
&= \int_0^3 \int_0^3 (18 + 12 y - 12 z - 4 y z + 8 z^2 - 2 z^3) \, dz \, dy \\
&= \int_0^3 \left[(18 + 12 y)z - (6 + 2y)z^2 + 8 \frac{z^3}{3} - \frac{z^4}{2} \right]_0^3 \, dy \\
&= \int_0^3 \left[3(18 + 12 y) - 9(6 + 2y) + 8(9) - \frac{81}{2} \right] \, dy \\
&= \int_0^3 (\frac{63}{2} + 18y) \, dy \\
&= \left[\frac{63}{2}y + 9y^2 \right]_0^3 \\
&= \frac{63(3)}{2} + 9(9) \\
&= \frac{351}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you , sir. This has solved my doubt :)

Comment: The two interpretations of the set are just two ways to consider the integration limits. We could integrate, or "continuous add" function values from left to right on the pictures first (along x-direction) from x = 0 to x = 6-2z (we get cut off by the slanted plane). We then integrate this from z = 0 to z = 3, seen on the picture as integrating this upward. Then, we integrate this function from y = 0 to y = 3, from front to back on the picture. You can find the limits of integration by drawing out the planes and see the region they enclose and how the planes form boundaries.

Comment: But when i tried solving using these limits , the answer comes out to be different . Will the limits be x = 0 to x = 6, z= 0 to z = (6-x )/2 and y = 0 to 3 ?

Comment: Yes. Using those limits of integration should give you the same answer. Just worked it out and got 351/2